# Find slope tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $(\pi/2,\pi/2,0)$ in direction parallel to xy-plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line, slope

Let $f(x,y)=x^2\sin(x+y)$ be any surface. Find the slope of the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $(\pi/2,\pi/2,0)$ in the direction parallel to $xy$-plane.
I am new to multivariable calculus and have no idea how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)=x^2\sin(x+y)$

Tangent plane at $P(\pi/2,\pi/2,0)$

Let's write partial derivatives
$$f'_x=x^2 \cos (x+y)+2 x \sin (x+y);\;f'_y=x^2 \cos (x+y)$$
Tangent plane has equation
$$z=f(x_P,y_P)+f'_x(x_P,y_P)(x-x_P)+f'_y(x_P,y_P)(y-y_P)$$
That is
$$z=-\frac{\pi ^2 x}{4}-\frac{\pi ^2 y}{4}+\frac{\pi ^3}{4}$$
If we want the equation of the tangent  line  parallel to $xy$ plane we consider the intersection of the tangent plane with the plane parallel to the plane $xy$ passing through $P$ which is $z=0$

In the plane $z=0$ the equation of the line is

$$-\frac{\pi ^2 x}{4}-\frac{\pi ^2 y}{4}+\frac{\pi ^3}{4}=0$$
which simplified gives

$\color{red}{y=-x+\pi}$

So the answer is that the slope is $m=-1$

Hope this is useful

Comment: sir like we have slope of tangent line parallel to xz plane euqal to partial derivative of f with respect to x at that point and similarly for tangent line parallel to yz plane it is partial derivative of f with respect to y... don't we have a direct formula for the one parallel to xy-plane

Comment: also f(x_p, y_p) =0 isn't it?

Comment: @SoLo I don't have a direct formula for the line, but only for the plane and yes $f(x_p,y_p)=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your approach is very clear cut.